# Calculating LST from Landsat 5 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: ndvi, landsat, surface, land-surface-temperature

I'm trying to write a code for Land Surface Temperature (LST) from Landsat 5 images in Google Earth Engine. I'm using the code of this question as a guide and I succeeded but I'm not sure to be right my code.

Any suggestions/ideas for LST code?

```
var LC5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate('2008-01-01','2009-01-01')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH',164))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW',37))
.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUD_COVER',10))

.map(function(img){


 
  var clipms = img.clip(geometry);
  var ndvi = clipms.normalizedDifference(['B4','B3']);
  
  var lse = ndvi.expression('1.009 + 0.047 * log(ndvi)',{'ndvi':ndvi});
  var emissivity1 = ndvi.where(ndvi.lt(-0.185),0.995);
  var emissivity2 = emissivity1
  .where(ndvi.gte(-0.185).and(ndvi.lt(0.157)),0.985);
  var emissivity3 = emissivity2
  .where(ndvi.gte(0.157).and(ndvi.lte(0.727)),lse);
  var emissivity4 = emissivity3
  .where(ndvi.gt(0.727),0.990);
  
  var tir = img.select('B6');
  var tirclip = tir.clip(geometry);
  var rad = tirclip.multiply(0.055375).add(1.18243);
  var bt = rad.expression('1260.56/(log(607.76/rad + 1))',{'rad':rad});
  
  var lst = emissivity4
  .expression('(bt)/( 1 + ( (bt * 11.5)/(14380.0) ) * log(e))',
  {'bt':bt,'e':emissivity4}); 
  
  var lstcel = lst.subtract(273.15);
  
  return lstcel.rename('LST')
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});

Map.addLayer(LC5,[],'lc5');
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. The question you have referred is not linked. Kindly [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/465577/edit) the post. Asking for suggestion or opinion on codes are discouraged in this site. LST calculation has specific formula which you can find in literature. If you get the desired result using the correct formula, you are okay. GIS SE is a problem solving site. If you face any error while running the code, you can ask here.